# headless-selenium-for-win using Python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, headless-browser

I found a headless IE from this github project [headless-selenium-for-win](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win/releases)

Which has the following files

```
desktop_utils.exe
headless_ie_selenium.exe
```

I extracted these files to `C:\Selenium\headless-selenium`

I used Selenium Python library to control IE(GUI) using `IEDriverServer.exe` which works well but when I use `headless_ie_selenium.exe` my script just went into endless execution and prints nothing.

Here is my Python Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


#driver = webdriver.Ie(r"C:/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe")
driver = webdriver.Ie(r"C:/Selenium/headless-selenium/headless_ie_selenium.exe")
driver.get("www.google.com")
googleSearch = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
googleSearch.send_keys("Selenium")
googleSearch.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

import time
time.sleep(4)

print driver.title
```

Comment: I found using phantomjs  with selenium very effective.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm have to use IE for testing a site which was developed using ActiveX object.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `endless execution`? You don't tear down the driver instance in the script you posted, so one shouldn't expect the window to close.

Comment: @duhaime I mean, I waited for a long time but the interpreter didn't execute `print driver.title` statement

Comment: FWIW, due to the way the IEDriver actually works and how it interacts with IE (it is *vastly* different to the other drivers), fudging it to work "headless" is not supported!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the path of `IEDriverServer.exe` to System Variable `path` and after restarting my system the everything works fine.

Comment: I put all three files in the same folder as my main executable.  [ IEDriverServer.exe, desktop_utils.exe, headless_ie_selenium.exe ].  Easy packaging & distribution.

Answer (score -1):

May be problem in slashes...

Your path: C:/Selenium/headless-selenium/headless_ie_selenium.exe

**Try this:** C:\Selenium\headless-selenium\headless_ie_selenium.exe

and another:

Your: driver.get("www.google.com")

**Try this:** driver.get("https://www.google.com")