# Python Selenium PhantomJS login dialog

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver, phantomjs

Please note, this question is `Python 3.5.2`, only Python answers will be accepted. Unless this can definitely be handled in Java? Automating a process as part of an internal project. Everything works just fine using the `IE webdriver`, but not `phantomJS` web driver (which is expected due to limited functionality). However, a work-around / solution is required.

When opening the internal site, a `Windows Security login dialog box` comes up prompting for a username, password and press 'Ok'. With the `IE web driver`, it is handled just fine with:

```
loginAlert = driver.switch_to_alert()
loginAlert.authenticate(username, password)
```

The javascript:

```
driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function(){return true;}")
```

Being run before loading the page that gives the prompt, doesn't seem to confirm the login alert, for either phantom or IE. Even if it did, this doesn't type in the login details. As mentioned, it's a Windows Security prompt from the browser, not an element.

Once logged in, the page is reloaded with an `ASP.NET_SessionId` Cookie which expires once the session is ended. I've tried logging in through IE, then adding the cookie into Phantom, but it doesn't seem to match up the domains.

I've tried using:

```
driver.save_screenshot(filename) to see what's happening in phantom
```

Which works with `IE driver`, but with `PhantomJS`, only a transparent image is saved. The whole `http://username:pass@site.com` thing doesn't work for either IE or phantom driver. It can't load / use the URL when this is done.

How can the Windows Security login dialog be handled, or worked around? I tried looking into alternatives, such as `pyvirtualdisplay`, but found no information on how to get this working with `Python 3` on `windows`.

I have also tried setting `phantomjs` desired capabilities custom header authentication, but that doesn't seem to do anything for this either.

I have also tried using `ActionChains`, however they don't work when the Alert is there (in either IE or phantom driver). An `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` is thrown, even if this is caught and you try to perform the actions, once caught, the alert seems to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad!

Whilst the `username:pass@domain.com` didn't work in the `IE webdriver` - `it did work in the PhantomJS web driver.`

However, the website has limited browser compatibility - it `doesn't load properly in either Chrome or Firefox`, it is IE particular.

`PhantomJS` seems to handle the site the same way as Chrome / Firefox based on page source comparisons.

As such, `I am trying to find a way to make the current IE driver invisible / hidden.`

I have found:

[headless-selenium-for-win using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748631/headless-selenium-for-win-using-python)

However, despite the user here saying they got it to work, when I try to `initialize the driver, it just hangs, the code doesn't proceed and no error messages are provided.`

Asking another question regarding this.